# Утечка памяти в перегрузке оператора равенства

Tags: c++, ооп, память

После написания программы проверил на утечку памяти с помощью *valgrind*, получил наибольшую проблему в данной части.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прилагаю части кода, где возникает наибольшая утечка памяти.

**wrapper.cpp:26**

```
containter.push_back(new Simple_Text(buf));
```

где `containter` - объект типа *list*, собирающий в себя указатели на элементы абстрактного класса. Он хранится в классе до вызова функции вывода элементов текста, после которого с начала и до конца происходит обход, вывод и удаление элементов.

**simple_text.h:10**

```
Simple_Text(const Text& text) {txt = text;};
```

Класс `Text` - аналог класса `string`, содержащий в себе поле текста `wchar_t* str` и поле длины текста `unsigned int len`. `Simple_Text` - класс абзаца текстового документа, единственным полем которого является `Text txt`.

**text.cpp:26**

```
const Text& Text::operator=(const Text& cpd) {
    len = cpd.len;
    delete[] str;
    str = new wchar_t [len+1];
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
        str[i] = cpd.str[i];
    str[len] = L'\0';
    return *this;
};
```

Где может возникнуть утечка памяти?

Comment: указатель это не объект, а просто число. И вектор указателей `containter.push_back(new Simple_Text(buf));` ничего делать с ними не будет. Вы должны сами удалять объект по указателю лично.

Comment: @AlexGlebe немного дополнил вопрос. Данный вектор находится в классе, который хранит в себе этот вектор. В нем два метода - чтение файла, заполняющий данный контейнер указателей, и вывод обработанного файла, который берет элементы вектора и выводит их, удаляя из вектора. Это перевело утечку памяти из раздела "indirectly lost" в "directly".

Comment: Добавьте [mcve].